# Method to track event using fabric

Tags: ios, swift, google-fabric

I want to track event using fabric. Which is working for me via using

```
import Answers
    func trackEvent() {

    Answers.logCustomEvent(withName: "testEvent", customAttributes: ["Category":"test", "Player":50])
}
```

But I have to import the answers class in every view, where I need to track any event. Is there any other way or method to track events without the need of importing answer class every single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? Create a class say `Tracker` and import `Answers` their.

```
import Answers
class Tracker {
    static func logCustomEvent(withName:String, customAttributes:[String:Any]) {
        Answers.logCustomEvent(withName: withName, customAttributes: customAttributes)
    }
}
```

And then use your class everywhere without importing anything.

```
Tracker.logCustomEvent(withName: "testEvent", customAttributes: ["Category":"test", "Player":50])
```